# Change features of react app based on build environment target

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm in the process of developing a react app that will be deployed to two different places, one having slightly different and restricted "functionality" of the other. Think of a "freeware" version vs a "commercial" version type scenario.

I'm looking at using the `DefinePlugin` and `if` statements throughout the code to restrict certain areas from being compiled into the restricted version, but I'm not sure this is the best way to do it. As is always the case with React I'm always on the hunt for the best way to do something and I can't seem to find much info on this sort of deployment.

Help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You should consider managing these different versions of your application using code branches in your SCM. Using `DefinePlugin` might work, but will get hard to maintain down the road. This would also simplify things from a deployment standpoint as well.

Assuming you are using git, you could use the `master` branch for the "commercial version", and you could create a `freeware-master` branch for the "freeware version".

Then when you develop features in other feature branches, you can choose to merge them to `master` only, or both `master` and `freeware-master` via pull requests.